# Adjusting For Each variables

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having trouble with something I think is fairly basic. Can someone please help?

How can I adjust the "cell" value within the For Each loop?  Since I delete a row, my "cell" counter gets thrown off and skips a row each time one is removed.

I think I can fix it by adjusting the counter, but need to replace: Set cell = cell - 1

```
For Each row In pipelineRange.Rows
  For Each cell In row.Cells
    If cell.Value = "EXIT" Then
       cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("EXITS").Range("A" & Sheets("EXITS").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1)
       Sheets("PIPELINE TRACKER").Activate
       cell.EntireRow.Delete
       Set cell = cell - 1
    ElseIf cell.Value = 1 Then
       cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("COMPLETED").Range("A" & Sheets("COMPLETED").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1)
       Sheets("PIPELINE TRACKER").Activate
       cell.EntireRow.Delete
       Set cell = cell - 1
    End If
 Next cell
Next row
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting always go backwards to avoid this. For example:

```
For X = Range("A" & Rows.count).end(xlup).row to 2 step -1
    If Range("A" & X).Text = "Delete Me" then rows(X).delete
Next
```

We know the first row of the range here: `pipelineRange.Row` We also know the number of rows in the range here `pipelineRange.Rows.Count` if we add them together then minus 1 we will get the final row of the range

Something like this perhaps

```
Sub Something()
Dim X As Long
For X = pipelineRange.Row + pipelineRange.Rows.Count - 1 To pipelineRange.Row Step -1
    For Each cell In Rows(X).Cells
        If cell.Value = "EXIT" Then
           cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("EXITS").Range("A" & Sheets("EXITS").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
           Sheets("PIPELINE TRACKER").Activate
           cell.EntireRow.Delete 'You could change this for rows(X).delete if you like
        ElseIf cell.Value = 1 Then
           cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("COMPLETED").Range("A" & Sheets("COMPLETED").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
           Sheets("PIPELINE TRACKER").Activate
           cell.EntireRow.Delete 'You could change this for rows(X).delete if you like
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```